# proving log x is continuous on $(a, \infty)$ wihtout using mvt

Tags: real-analysis

#### PRoblem: Prove $f(x) = \log x$ is continuous on $(a, \infty)$ $a>0$.

### TRY:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary. let $x >a$ We suppose $|x-a| < \delta $. Notice

$$ |\log x - \log a | =|  \log (x/a) | $$

Notce if $a>1$, then $\log(x/a) < x/a - 1 = \frac{x-a}{a} $. if $a<1$, then $| \log (x/a) | = - \log (x/a) > - x/a +1 \implies \log(x/a) < \frac{x-a}{a}$. Thus, in any case

$$ |log(x/a)| \leq \frac{x-a}{a} < \delta /a $$

Thus, choose $\delta = a \epsilon $ and we are done.

Is this a correct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof needs some modification. To prove continuity **on** $(a,\infty)$ you need to show that $\log$ is continuous at any point $c \in (a,\infty)$.

If $x > c$, then you can use your first estimate.

$$|\log x - \log c| = \log(x/c) = \log[1 + (x-c)/c]< \frac{x-c}{c} =  \frac{|x-c|}{c}.$$

If $a < x < c$, then

$$|\log x - \log c| = \log(c/x) = \log[1 + (c-x)/x]< \frac{c-x}{x} < \frac{c-x}{a} = \frac{|x-c|}{a}.$$

Now you can find a suitable $\delta$ that applies to either case.

Answer (score 0):

If $a<1$ and x>a, log(x/a) is still positive, so I guess it's not a correct one.